# MarkLogic search query multiple duplicates, grab latest results based off timestamp field

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I've got a dataset that looks like this:

```
    {
     "id": 1234,
     "name": "name-1",
     "timestamp: "2022-02-10T13:48:32.195344Z",
    }
```

There are several thousand documents with unique id's in the database I'm trying to grab.  However the issue is the `"name"` property can change with each id, so there can be multiple documents that have the same id but different name.

For my result set I'm trying to return a full list of all the documents of each unique id-name pair, but only one document for each pair that is the document with the latest timestamp.

For example with four documents with the id of "1234" and "name-2", I'd only want to return one of those documents that has the latest timestamp.

There are millions of documents in this dataset, so performance is a concern here as well.

Is there any way to build this query with cts functions or similar?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to process all of the documents in one module execution, then you could do something like this, to use a map with a composite key using the `id` and `name` as the key, and then test whether there is a `timestamp` and if greater or less than the current docs timestamp:

```
let $map := map:new()
let $_ :=
  for $doc in cts:search(doc(), $query)
  let $id := $doc/id
  let $name := $doc/name
  let $timestamp := $doc/timestamp/xs:dateTime(.)
  let $key := $id || $name
  let $old_value := map:get($map, $key)/timestamp/xs:dateTime(.)
  where not(exists($old_value) and $old_value gt $timestamp)
  return map:put($map, $key, $doc)
return 
  for $key in map:keys($map)
  return map:get($map, $key)
```

However, that might be slow and runs the risk of blowing the Expanded Tree Cache. If you can index those fields, then you could use [`cts:value-tuples()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-tuples) with similar logic:

```
let $map := map:new()
let $_ :=
  for $tuple in cts:value-tuples(
    ( 
      cts:element-reference(xs:QName("id")),
      cts:element-reference(xs:QName("name")),
      cts:element-reference(xs:QName("timestamp")),
      cts:uri-reference()
    ),
    (), 
    $query
  )
  let $id := $tuple[1]
  let $name := $tuple[2]
  let $timestamp := $tuple[3]
  let $key := $id || $name
  let $old_value := map:get($map, $key)[3]
  where not(exists($old_value) and $old_value gt $timestamp)
  return map:put($map, $key, $tuple)
return 
  for $key in map:keys($map)
  return (: this returns the URI, you could also wrap with doc() to fetch them :)
    map:get($map, $key)[4]
```